# Meteor keep track of user sign ins

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I would like to keep track of the amount of times that a user has logged into the application to either:

- Remind them on their first visit to complete their profile
- If profile is not complete, every X amount of visits remind user to complete

I'm not sure if the proper way to do this would be adding a key value to the users collection, or tie login to a new collection which counts up one each time a login occurs.

Is there a built in method to keep track of login successes?

Answer (score 2):

Yup. You can even keep track of login failures.

From http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin:

```
Accounts.onLogin(function() {
   // track successful login here. You can just use Meteor.user() to find out which user.
});

Accounts.onLoginFailure(function() {
   // track failed login here. 
});
```

There is even a "validate login attempt" method where you could potentially screen your users:

[Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(func)](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validateloginattempt):

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(loginInfo) {
     // loginInfo.user returns a valid user object, if logged in successfully. Maybe tie this one to a collection, and do some checks etc.
     // you can even use loginInfo.connection to see where the user has connected from (e.g. IP address.. perhaps)


     return true; // return false if you want to 'bounce' this user.
});
```

Note: These can be done server-side only.